# Boundary of {1, 2, 3} ∪ (2, 4)

Tags: real-analysis

I made a mistake earlier in assuming {1,2,3} was neither open or closed. I fond that the complement was open, hence the set was closed.

Now here is where I am having trouble: Finding the boundary of {1, 2, 3} ∪ (2, 4). The only common point between the two is (2).

Where would I begin?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the common points are, because you are taking the union, not the intersection. (Also, $3$ is a common point but $2$ is not.) Can you simplify $\{1,2,3\} \cup (2,4)$?

Comment: If you simplify , the only union between the two is just 3?

Comment: The union is the set of all points that belong to either of the two sets. Certainly $3$ is not the only such point.

Comment: So would it be {2,3}

Comment: Is $1$ in either of the sets? If so, it is in their union. What about $\pi$?

Comment: Yea, but this is where IM getting confused. Wouldnt the union of 1 be 2?

Comment: The union of $\{1,2,3\}$ and $(2,4)$ is $\{1\}\bigcup [2,4)$. Can you find the boundary of this set?

Answer (score 1):

$(2, 4)$ is the set of all numbers between, but not including, $2$ and $4$. This includes $3$, so $\{1,2,3\} \cup(2, 4)$ is redundant since both sets have $3$. Therefore, we can get rid of it from the first set, leaving us with $\{1,2\} \cup (2, 4)$.

Then, since $2$ is not in $(2, 4)$, but is on the boundary on it, we can easily include $2$ in $(2, 4)$ by simply closing the left boundary on this interval, so we have $[2, 4)$. We can now get rid of the $2$ from the first set, leaving us with $\{1\} \cup [2, 4)$, which is the union of disjoint sets separated by a non-zero distance, so we can find the boundary of their union by finding the union of their boundaries.

Clearly, the boundary of $\{1\}$ is just $\{1\}$. Also, the boundary of $[2, 4)$ is just $\{2, 4\}$. The union of the two is $\{1,2,4\}$, so that is the boundary of the original set.

Comment: ah, I see where I have made the mistake. I didnt close of [2,4) and left it open (2,4).

Answer (score 0):

Check the definition of boundary point: a point such that every neighborhood of the point contains a point in the set as well as a point outside the set. Make sure you have the union correct, it's $\{1\} \cup [2,4).$ Which points of this set satisfy the definition of boundary point? [Hint: there are three of them; there is no requirement that a boundary point of the set belongs to the set]